# Getting below error while starting nodeagent

Tags: websphere

ORBRas E com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket P=146590:O=0:CT ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread.
Exception=[ java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use. - received while attempting to open server socket on port 9101 ]. [9/28/22 22:42:29:445 GMT+05:30] 00000001 WsServerImpl E WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup

Comment: Did you have trouble stopping the nodeagent?  This message happens when you try to start a server, like the nodeagent when it did not stop cleanly (or even there was no attempt to stop it) ... and the port is still in use.   If you can't end the nodeagent cleanly to free up the port, try restarting the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command line terminal and execute $WAS_HOME/bin/stopNode.sh

Answer (score 0):

I just think please healcheck service and port use for agent

```
ps -ef |grep nodeagent
ps -ef |grep 9101
```

and please stop nodeagent with command:

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/TPSrv01/bin/stopNode.sh
```

and waiting for long time than 5 minutes please `kill -9 processid(nodeagent)`

and Start nodeagent with command: `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/TPSrv01/bin/startNode.sh`

Thanks and regards

tandn

Comment: Hi Taneto now services are running with wasadmin user but while hitting url we getting internal server error in plugin in log we getting these error

Comment: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle
ERROR: ws_common: websphereRequestHandler: Failed to find an app server to handle this request

Comment: Please share status in Web Console for nodeagent, so you can remove and readd to nodeagent, Thanks and regards, tandn

Comment: Node agent running all services are running

Comment: Please share log with grep -E "error|Error|ERROR|DEBUG" in SystemOut.log in nodeagent